# Why can't I get the view contnet after using setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) to a webview on Android?

Tags: android, webview

My original intent is trying to solve the flicking problem when loading content with the webview class.

Some threads say the problem is about `Hardware acceleration` property. So I am trying to disable that feature with the following code to fix it in two ways:

- `myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`
- `android:layerType="software"`

But both of them can't work properly. After applying the code, there's no content can be seen in webview. You can see the difference from following pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I encounter the same issue when building with api level 19